# Step in a proof involving submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, expected-value

Let $X_t$ be a submartingale and $\tau_n$ a sequence of stopping time.
Therefore $E[X_{\tau_n}]$ is an increasing sequence.
In a proof that I'm reading I see the following:

Since $E[\sup_t|X_t|]<\infty$ (is an assumption), then $(E[X_{\tau_n}])_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is $\underline {also}$ bounded and $(E[X_{\tau_n}])_{n\in \mathbb N}$  is convergent.

What I don't understand is why $E[\sup_t|X_t|]<\infty$ imply that $(E[X_{\tau_n}])_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is bounded? I always thought that being $<\infty$ was different from being bounded, but this sentence with the use of "also" make me uncertain about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|X_{\tau_n}| \leq \sup_t |X_t|$, which proves $E[X_{\tau_n}] \leq E[\sup_t |X_t|]<\infty$ for all $n$.

You're right that just having $E[X_{\tau_n}]<\infty$ for each $n$ does *not* imply the entire sequence is bounded. However, notice that we have the *same* upper bound for each $n$, namely $E[\sup_t|X_t|]$. This is enough to prove the sequence is bounded.

Comment: thank you, I understood this point. If you wanna give a look I added a second question

Comment: You should generally make a new question rather than adding questions to your original post. Your new question is more likely to be seen that way, and people who answered your original question might not be able to just edit their questions to add more answers on the spot.

Comment: Okey, you are right. Here is the new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516143/proof-of-martingale-convergence-using-fatous-lemma