# Proof of Martingale convergence using Fatou's lemma

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, random-variables, martingales

Let $X_t$ be a submartingale.
Knowing that $\sup_t|X_t| \in L^1$ and that $X_t \to X_{\infty}$ a.s. and in $L^1$, I want to prove that $$X_t\le E[X_\infty|\mathcal F_t]$$ 
using Fatou's lemma for limsup $$E[X_\infty]=E\big[\limsup_t X_t \big] \ge \limsup_t E[X_t]\ge E[X_t]$$
where the last inequality hold because $E[X_t]$ is an increasing sequence, however I'm not sure of this last step. Indeed it seems to me that (being an increasing sequence) also $$\limsup_t E[X_t]=E[X_\infty]$$
so the inequality cannot be true.

$1)$ So, is it true that $\limsup_t E[X_t]=E[X_\infty]$?

$2)$ how could i prove the statement then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it's true that $\limsup_t \mathbb{E}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}(X_{\infty})$?

Yes, it's true. By assumption, $X_t \to X_{\infty}$ in $L^1$ and this implies $\lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}(X_{\infty})$. Since $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a submartingale, this is equivalent to $\sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}(X_{\infty})$.

> How could I prove the statement then?

You need to apply Fatou's lemma for conditional expectations: \begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X_{\infty} \mid \mathcal{F}_t) &= \mathbb{E}(\limsup_{T \to \infty} X_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \\ &\stackrel{(\star)}{\geq} \limsup_{T \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_T \mid \mathcal{F}_t) \\ &\stackrel{(\star \star)}{\geq} X_t\end{align*}

where $(\star)$ follows from Fatou's lemma for conditional expectation and $(\star \star)$ follows from the submartingale property.

Comment: Okey, I also solved in that way at the end, but I was unsure on the last step. Indeed, how can I be sure that $T>t$ s.t. I can apply the submartingale property? Because if $T<t$ then I would have $\limsup_{T \to infty}X_T$ (being $\mathcal F_t$ measurable). I think that in your last inequality you mean $X_t$, not $E[X_t]$

Comment: @Buddy_ We are only interested in large $T$ because we are considering $\limsup$ as $T \to \infty$. If you are unsure about this part, then take a look at the very definition of "limsup".